# Why deleting pointer to list causes core dump

Tags: c++, stl, delete-operator

While learning [BFS from geekforgeek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/), I notice that there is no `delete adj` for the `new list<int>` array:

```
 adj = new list<int>[V];
```

Will it cause a memory leak? For this question, I made a [demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a0fcc8edd072c6) to using delete to release the memory explicitly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> *adj = new list<int>[3];
    cout << adj->size() << endl;

    delete adj;
}
```

`delete` operation will cause coredump. So why does deleting pointer to list cause core dump?  How to release the memory by `new` operation?

Comment: You can't `delete` a pointer created by `new[]`. You need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: "_why does deleting pointer to list_" `adj` is not a pointer to `list`, though. It's a pointer to an array of `list`s.

Comment: @tkausl, yes, it is. I made a stupid mistake... Thanks

Comment: @tkausl - you should post it as an answer

Comment: A `std::list` is a container that dynamically manages the objects that it contains.  It makes very little sense to dynamically allocate a `std::list` with `new` or `new[]`.

Comment: @Eljay: There are plenty of reasons, especially since `list` can (since C++17) be instantiated with incomplete types, allowing it to be part of a tree node.  Having a variable number of `list`s in an array is also legitimate, although of course one should usually use `std::vector<std::list<…>>` then.